# BadRequest - error message contains property names, not properties from json attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, fluentvalidation, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a simple web API using ASP.NET Core 5.0.
When the user is doing a POST request I'm doing validation using https://fluentvalidation.net/ (version 10.3.6).

Problem is that for bad requests I'm getting this response:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "City": [
            "'city' must not be empty."
        ],
        "Street": [
            "'street' must not be empty."
        ],
        "PostalCode": [
            "'postal_code' must not be empty."
        ],
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-6bbc01ce495bd2408a1b03d6475211a1-636870d13ea0934f-00"
}
```

instead of:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "city": [
            "'city' must not be empty."
        ],
        "street": [
            "'street' must not be empty."
        ],
        "postal_code": [
            "'postal_code' must not be empty."
        ],
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-6bbc01ce495bd2408a1b03d6475211a1-636870d13ea0934f-00"
}
```

The property names are the property names from my dto, not from the attributes as they should be.
So it should return `city` not `City`, `street` not `Street` and `postal_code` not `PostalCode`

In `Startup.cs` In configuring validation with the above:

```
services.AddControllers(x =>
{
}).AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
    };
    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
}).AddFluentValidation(fv =>
{
    fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
});

ValidatorOptions.Global.DisplayNameResolver = GetPropertyNamesFromJsonPropertyAttribute;
```

my custom display name resolver (used to read property name from the attribute):

```
private string GetPropertyNamesFromJsonPropertyAttribute(Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo, LambdaExpression expression)
{
    var displayName = memberInfo.Name;
    var jsonPropertyAttribute = memberInfo.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>();
    if (jsonPropertyAttribute != null)
    {
        return jsonPropertyAttribute.PropertyName;
    }
    var jsonPropertyNameAttribute = memberInfo.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyNameAttribute>();
    if (jsonPropertyNameAttribute != null)
    {
        return jsonPropertyNameAttribute.Name;
    }

    return displayName;
}
```

sample dto:

```
public class CreateCompanyDto
{
    [JsonProperty("name"), JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("city"), JsonPropertyName("city")]
    public string? City { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("postal_code"), JsonPropertyName("postal_code")]
    public string? PostalCode{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("street"), JsonPropertyName("street")]
    public string? Street { get; set; }
}

public class CreateCompanyValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateCompanyDto>
{
    private readonly ICompanyRepository _companyRepository;
    private readonly ILogger<CreateCompanyValidator> _logger;

    public CreateCompanyValidator(ICompanyRepository companyRepository, ILogger<CreateCompanyValidator> logger)
    {
        _companyRepository = companyRepository;
        _logger = logger;

        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.City).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.PostalCode).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Street).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

All my controller inherits `ControllerBase`.

Comment: You mean the field name of the data type you return is not the same as the field name you define using the JsonPropertyName property?

Comment: @Chaodeng problem is the validator response (BadRequest with ModelState). I'm implementing this approach: https://maximgorbatyuk.github.io/blog/development/2021-02-20-snake-case-and-asp-net-core/. More info here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39010 this will be fixed in .NET 7